# I need help resolving an error with storybook init

Tags: angular, storybook

I am trying to initialize the storybook in a component library I've built, but I am running into issues with the command returning an error.

I have set up my workspace with a library and a test application. I am trying to add storybook, so I'm running `npx storybook@latest init` at my workspace root directory on a Windows machine. I have storybook 7.0.11

The error I get is this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 5133
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at new AngularJSON (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:50:689)
at generator (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:50:3150)
at async installStorybook (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:332:791)
at async doInitiate (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:337:707)
at async withTelemetry (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\core-server\dist\index.js:35:3422)
at async initiate (C:\Users\{}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\bc7e1e37fcb46ffc\node_modules\@storybook\cli\dist\generate.js:348:109)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a trailing comma in my angular.json file, which caused this error.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to first try deleting `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file and the try again .
2. if that does not work then  :

JUST Delete

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

AND

```
C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
```

3. It can also be due to network failure and just Run this inside your existing project’s root directory:

Comment: I tried deleting node_modules and package lock in my projects root that didn't help. I also deleted the npm folder in my roaming, all that contained was the angular cli though which, I reinstalled. I still have the same error.

Comment: I did find the npm-cache folder in a different location which deleted storybook. However, the issue happened again afterwards.